# Can I sue my university for allowing me to take classes at the same time (schedule conflict)?

Tags: graduate-school, legal-issues

I took a class that started at 5:30. Another class I was taking started the same time. Can I get a refund or sue for this, as there should have been a message not letting me complete my schedule because of the conflict?

Comment: Why not check the times yourself when you enrolled and avoid a conflict?

Comment: Maybe this is regional, but I'm confused - any institution I've ever been involved with had a drop/add period at least in the first few weeks. Have you just asked your institutions registrar about changing your schedule? Example policy I found on a quick google: https://graduate.lclark.edu/offices/registrar/forms_and_resources/late_add_drop/ (this will vary by institution, there is no universal policy)

Comment: In my alma mater you would be automatically dropped from both of them, for failing to check the schedules. You may or may not get a notification before you show up for the final exam.

Comment: _Can I sue my university for allowing me to take classes at the same time?_ Yes, of course you can. In the US and most other countries I'm familiar with, anybody can sue anyone, for any reason. Now, whether you can _successfully_ sue, that is a different question...

Comment: Just a sidenote: Where I am from, people sometimes take lectures with some overlap because they do not learn from lectures anyway. So unless your presence is obligatory for all classes, it even makes sense for the system to allow you to do this.

Comment: At the schools I've been at, courses scheduled at the same time also have their final exams at the same time. This even if you skip lectures, you might be in for a world of hurt later.

Comment: This sounds like a typical case of "I made a mistake, now I want to sue someone for it."

Answer (score 7):

No, that sounds like something that you should be responsible for avoiding yourself.  It might be nice if the school kept better track of this kind of thing for you, but it is ultimately your responsibility to know what you are enrolling in and paying for.  You might be able to get some kind of tuition refund, if you are really polite and persistent, but even that is quite unlikely.  A successful lawsuit is simply not going to happen.

Answer (score 5):

if you sue:

- You have a low probability of winning
- Your "damages" and the amount of money to be won, seem low
- You will likely have lawyer's fees and other cost of litigation
- You will waste your time and focus
- Your relationship with the university will be damaged
- Your reputation will likely be damaged

I hope that list helps.